# Handling multiple optional parameters in Spring

Tags: java, performance, rest, spring, hibernate

I have an endpoint in my RestAPI which can receive 3 optional parameters and then find information in the database with these parameters, also it is possible to combine the parameters. So, in my controller I take a Map<String, Object> which contains these parameters and then pass it to the service level, where I check which parameters were passed and then I call a specific DAO method, depends on which combination of parameters do I have. Params A and B are of type String, and C is a Map. So in the service level it looks like this:

```
public Set<ResultEntry> getByParameters(Map<String, Object> query) {
    Set<ResultEntry> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (query.containsKey("a") && query.containsKey("b") && query.containsKey("c")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByABC(
                (String) query.get("a"), (String) query.get("b"),
                (Map<String, String>) query.get("c")
        ));
    } else if (query.containsKey("a") && query.containsKey("b") && !query.containsKey("c")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByAB(
                (String) query.get("a"), (String) query.get("b")
        ));
    } else if (query.containsKey("a") && !query.containsKey("b") && query.containsKey("c")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByAC(
                (String) query.get("a"), (Map<String, String>) query.get("c")
        ));
    } else if (!query.containsKey("a") && query.containsKey("b") && query.containsKey("c")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByBC(
                (String) query.get("b"), (Map<String, String>) query.get("c")
        ));
    } else if (query.size() == 1 && query.containsKey("a")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByA((String) query.get("a")));
    } else if (query.size() == 1 && query.containsKey("b")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByB((String) query.get("b")));
    } else if (query.size() == 1 && query.containsKey("c")) {
        result.addAll(myDao.getByC((Map<String, String>) query.get("c")));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Everything works fine, but I feel like this is not the best way to deal with such situations, using if-statements for each possible combination, so how can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it works, the major issue with this approach is its extreme complexity and concreteness. If a new parameter `d` enters the game, it will became hellish to maintain!

*What can be done to improve the current implementation, without changing the approach?*

- there are many repetitions of `.containsKey(arg)` calls. They can be extracted to respective `boolean`s like `hasA`, `hasB` -> the code will be more readable.
- there are many redundant casts. `(String) query.get("a")` and the others can be extracted into respective local `var a = (String) query.get("a")` -> it will also become shorter and more readable.
- I think that the `result` variable might be avoided, if `myDao.get*` methods already return `Set`s.

*How the design can be improved?*

For the solution below, I suppose that the interface of the `myDao` object cannot be changed. If it could, there might be ways to play with method overloads, attempting to apply a pattern.

The current API of `myDao` looks very concrete and clear. The names of the methods mention each expected parameter and the order and the number of the arguments is predictable for each case. So the solution that I suggest below is based on the calculation of the method to invoke by reflection.

The name of the method to invoke on `myDao` can be calculated as follows:

```java
private String calculateDaoMethodToInvoke(boolean hasA, boolean hasB, boolean hasC) {
  var builder = new StringBuilder("getBy");
  if (hasA) {
    builder.append("A");
  }
  if (hasB) {
    builder.append("B");
  }
  if (hasC) {
    builder.append("C");
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

We can also calculate the arguments to invoke this method with:

```java
private Object[] calculateDaoMethodArgs(String a, String b, Map<String, String> c) {
  return Stream.of(a, b, c)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull)
               .toArray();
}
```

Now, since we know the name of the target method and the parameters to use, the Java reflection features can be used to produce the results.

We can define a wrapper around the `Class.getMethod` call, in order to retrieve the reference to the method of `myDao` to be invoked:

```java
private Method extractDaoMethod(String daoMethodName, Object[] params) {
  try {
    var paramTypes = Arrays.stream(params)
                           .map(Object::getClass)
                           .toArray(Class[]::new);
    return Dao.class.getMethod(daoMethodName, paramTypes);
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
  }
}
```

And its invocation can also be wrapped:

```java
private Collection<ResultEntry> getByParams(String daoMethodName, Object[] params) {
  var method = extractDaoMethod(daoMethodName, params);
  try {
    return (Collection<ResultEntry>) method.invoke(myDao, params);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
  }
}
```

**Finally**, the `getByParameters` method is reduced to the following:

```java
public Set<ResultEntry> getByParameters(Map<String, Object> query) {
  var a = (String) query.get("a");
  var b = (String) query.get("b");
  var c = (Map<String, String>) query.get("c");

  var daoMethodName = calculateDaoMethodToInvoke(a != null, b != null, c != null);
  var daoArgs = calculateDaoMethodArgs(a, b, c);
  return new HashSet<>(getByParams(daoMethodName, daoArgs));
}
```

Please note that there are no more rigid `if - else if` chaining, the algo became flat.

This approach allows to easily introduce new parameters, provided that the `myDao` API continues to respect the same convention for its method names.

There can be further improvements. For example, the signatures of `calculateDaoMethodToInvoke` and `calculateDaoMethodArgs` can be changed in order to accept varargs (and corresponding changes in the implementation). It will make the introduction of new parameters even easier.